# textbox with validation rules still shows when a panel is moved on top of it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a wpf MVVM application and there is a textbox with validation in a user control. If there is an error the textbox has a red outlined around it and a red oval exclamation point next to it. My issue is when a panel is dragged on top of the textbox when it has an error the red ourline still hows. 
for example

[image]

[image]

this is the TextBox:

```
    <TextBox Margin="2,9" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="115" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource TextErrorStyle}" >
                <TextBox.Text >
                    <Binding Path="SelectedInfo" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <ExceptionValidationRule></ExceptionValidationRule>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>

 <Style x:Key="TextErrorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Controls.TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,40,2" />
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
                        <Border Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="20" Height="20" CornerRadius="10"
                            ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                            <TextBlock Text="!" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="white" />
                        </Border>
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                            <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="1" />
                        </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Is there a sendtoback or another option that put this textbox in the background when the panel is dragged over?

Comment: [`Panel.ZIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex?view=netframework-4.8). Or just define it earlier in the XAML.

Comment: I tried that it doesnt work I put it on the Grid containing the textbox

Comment: The validation template is displayed in an Adorner layer which gets the highest z-index by default. Can you explain how the panel is structured in the XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the [same issue](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/1240) and it solved by using `AdornerDecorator`.
Wrap your `TextBox` with `AdornerDecorator` and try again.

Comment: thanks it works wht is the md namespace in the git code

Comment: It's [MaterialDesign](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) namespace